# Difference between function and classmethod

Tags: python

In the [geopandas documentation](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis)

why is `geopandas.geodataframe.from_postgis()` is considered a classmethod rather than a function?  I thought a classmethod had to be called like `df.head(5)` on an object of the class whereas a function would be `head(df, 5)`

gdf.from_postgis() is called in a manner more consistent with a function in the example:

df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con)

It seems like a distinction without a difference since functions aren't that different from methods but thought it was worth finding out.

Comment: A classmethod is called on class or instance and receives the class as first parameter (similar to "self" for the usual instance method).

Comment: Because it's literally decorated with `@classmethod` [here on line 309](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/geodataframe.py). Also, I don't think it's possible to differentiate between a function, a method, a classmethod or a staticmethod based solely on the syntax of calling any of them. Say, is `thing` in `something.thing(4)` a method? I say `something` is a module and `thing` is a function of this module. No, wait, `something` is a class and `thing` is its classmethod!

Comment: Consider the docs about [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Comment: a `classmethod` is distinct from an instance method. An instance method receives the instances it was called on as the first argument, conventionally called `self`. a classmethod receives the *class* of the instance it is called on as the first argument (conventionally called `cls`). A classmethod can also be called on the class object itself, and will receive that same object as the first parameter.

Comment: thanks, should have put more effort into finding out. voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr, a classmethod is a method that takes itself, a class as an implicit first arguement. A method is a function that takes the calling object as an implicit first argument.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects